# Can't make python program run at boot with rc.local?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3

I tried to put the following before exit 0 in rc.local:

```
/FolderToThePyFile/piProgram.py &
```

The piProgram.py should start a local server, for a web-application. I tried to go to the browser to open the web-app, but the usual web-address doesn't work. Running the .py file only starts the server, it doesn't prompt for any user input. When I put in 'jobs' I don't see it running.

What am I doing wrong, and is there any way to fix it?

I am running Rasbian Os on Raspberry Pi 3 model B+.

Answer (score 1):

According to Raspberry Pi Docs

First

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Then you need to add the following before 'exit 0'

```
python /full/path/to/file/piProgram.py &
```

Raspberry Pi Docs: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

You need to specify 'python' before the path to the script

Comment: Thanks that helped. Do u know maybe how to then run a kiosk? I tried to add it after starting python program, but then it doesnt load the webpage

Comment: There are several steps to start a web server and boot into kiosk for the raspberry pi. (It's a whole new question altogether) Here's an in depth tutorial [link](https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen-tutorial/).